# How can I ignore default layout in svelte-kit?

Tags: sveltekit

I have a different layout I need for `./routes/login` pages...I'm trying to ignore the main `./routes/__layout.svelte` file as I dont' need the sidebar.

```
<script>
    import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.svelte';
</script>

<main>
    {#if segment === 'login'}
        <section>
            <slot />
        </section>
    {:else}
        <NavBar />
        <section>
            <slot />
        </section>
    {/if}
</main>

<style>
    main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    section {
        padding: 2.4rem;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f2f6fa;
    }
</style>
```

I get an error `segment is not defined`.

Comment: {#if segment === 'login'}. What’s a segment?

Comment: no idea...just got it from some old sapper SO question. I got it working with `page` but I'm still wondering if there's a way to create a layout under a route directory that ignores the main layout.

Comment: I will say, there are a whole lot of things with Svelte and Sveltekit that don't align with old tutorials and videos.  I've discovered best to stick to basics ( [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs) and [demos](https://svelte.dev/examples) ) stick to latest version of Sveltekit and roll your own.  oops. Meant to add the [svelte tutorial stuff](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics) too.

Comment: I'm actually starting to move away from svelte into just plain old javascript and web components. There's not much svelte provides that I really need besides simple routing and easy state management, but that can be done with some simple 20 line codes.

Comment: Yes, but... the concept of server side rendering, pre-compiling, localized CSS is sorta cool.  But yes, lots of stuff is difficult and frustrating.  Worst thing is you will get an error with a worthless error message.  And the submissions in StackOverflow aren't terribly helpful.

Comment: Can you reformat your storage system to:  1)`/routes/login`  and 2) `/routes/withsidebar/__layout.svelte`, then adjust the components accordingly?

Comment: yeah i guess i'll have to do that. I hate to add a new layer of folders for basic routes. Also the namespaced css is cool but with web components you get that already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Oct 2022 the accepted answer no longer works, as Named Layouts have been deprecated in favour of Advanced Layouts (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts).

You can group the login route with a directory whose name is wrapped in parentheses, then add a separate layout for pages in this group:

```
src/routes/
│ (app)/
│ ├ dashboard/
│ ├ item/
│ └ +layout.svelte
│ (marketing)/
│ ├ about/
│ ├ testimonials/
│ └ +layout.svelte
├ admin/
└ +layout.svelte
```

Group directories don't affect the URL pathname of the routes inside them.

Answer (score 6):

The answer I have provided does not work as of October 2022 because of the recent overhaul of the routing system. Please refer to the next answer.

<s>Why not just reset the layout, this is builtin for sveltekit. Just create a file named `__layout-foo.svelte` inside your `/routes` routes. Then you can put all the components you want inside the file
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/layouts#named-layouts</s>

Then address it in your page:

```
src/routes/my-special-page@foo.svelte
<h1>I am inside __layout-foo</h1>
```